# Writing Custom Menubar Extra

Tags: cocoa, menuitem, menubar

How can I make a Menu Extra like the Battery Meter in Cocoa? I can make a Status Item, but they are not movable.

Comment: So you want to create movable status item or just an additional status item?

Comment: An actual movable menu bar item, like the clock, and the AirPort thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NSMenuExtra` functionality is private API.  The best you can do (without delving into Apple's private frameworks and figuring it out yourself) is to use `NSStatusItem`.

Comment: I miss the days when it wasn't a private API. ;)

Comment: Well how can I use Apple's private API's while keeping support for 10.5 and 10.6?

Comment: @Tristan `NSMenuExtra` has been around for years.  However, I recommend that you just use a regular `NSStatusItem`.

Comment: OK. But how can I move an 'NSStatusItem' around in the Menu Bar like all other Menu Extras?

Comment: @Tristan you can't, because it's an `NSStatusItem`, not an `NSMenuExtra`.